# What version do I have?

Tags: steam, prison-architect

[Prison Architect has multiple versions available on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/233450/) and I'm wondering which edition I bought when I bought it. Through the DLC menu in the game's properties I can tell I have at least Aficionado, because the list of owned DLC contains both the soundtrack and art book from that edition. I also have all the games listed in Introversioner, but is there a way I can confirm? Perhaps the biggest question is whether or not I have the Name in Game edition, because I can't think of a way to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: [**Steam Account Information**](https://store.steampowered.com/account/)

You can find all your past purchases including their names on the [account information page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/), and in my case the list contains "Prison Architect Introversion".